# Como ter vários endereços em uma classe de pessoa?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Caso uma pessoa possua mais de um endereço. O código abaixo está correto?

```
public class Pessoa implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int codigo;
    private String descricao;
    private String dataNascimento;
    private String cpfcnpj;
    private PessoaEndereco pessoaEndereco;
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 7):

Não, desta forma você só conseguirá ter um endereço. Tem várias formas de permitir mais de um endereço, uma delas, talvez a mais simples, é esta:

```
public class Pessoa implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int codigo;
    private String descricao;
    private String dataNascimento;
    private String cpfcnpj;
    private ArrayList<PessoaEndereco> Enderecos;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/Aggregation.java).

Obviamente você deve ter métodos de acesso aos diversos endereços de forma fácil. A única mudança foi criar uma lista de endereços onde só cabia um.